# Animating a CAShapeLayer while moving its parent UIView via the center property

Tags: iphone, core-animation

**Update:**

There is no problem here. Turns out I was re-adding the animation every time I moved the point. Was else where in the code and I just totally glossed over it. Please ignore this question.

**end update**

I have a UIView which is just acting as a container for a UIImageView and a CAShaperLayer. The shape layer is drawing a circle and I have added a path animation to that shape layer to make it pulse. I want to be able to pulse the circle and move the container view at the same time using the center property of the UIView. However, when I set the center property on the container UIView, the pulse animation restarts from it's beginning no matter where it is at in it's animation.

How do I prevent the pulse animation from restarting?

Pulse animation:

```
CGRect startRect = CGRectMake(-10 + (self.bounds.size.width / 2),
                              -10 + (self.bounds.size.height / 2),
                              20,
                              20);

CGMutablePathRef fromPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(fromPath, NULL, startRect);

CGRect endRect = CGRectMake(-20 + (self.bounds.size.width / 2),
                            -20 + (self.bounds.size.height / 2),
                            40,
                            40);

CGMutablePathRef toPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(toPath, NULL, endRect);

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
animation.fromValue = (id)fromPath;
animation.toValue = (id)toPath;

CGPathRelease(fromPath);
CGPathRelease(toPath);

animation.duration = 2.0f;
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

[self.myCircleLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:self.pathAnimationKey];
```

I move the container view by doing:

```
self.myContainerView.center = newPoint;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the update above. Turns out there was no problem here.